# Access denied from ko.toJSON

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

my view model is very simple

```
var viewModel = {

    self: this,

    description: ko.observable('some description'),
    dateOfLost:  ko.observable('01/01/2012'),
    plaintiffFirmName: ko.observable('Johnson, Brand & Tall'),
    claimantName: ko.observable(),
    claimNum: ko.observable(),

    getFormData:function () {

        alert('event');

        GetClaimData();

    }
};
```

but when I'm trying to access model from html page

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJS($data)"></pre>
```

I'm getting error - Access denied. Can any one tell me why?
please note that all the fields above that line binded properly

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `self:this` from `viewModel`

```
var viewModel = {
    description: ko.observable('some description'),
    dateOfLost:  ko.observable('01/01/2012'),
```

in current context `this` is `window` object. The same error you will get by calling `ko.toJS(window)`

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tSfZ/)